# Cluster Index for a Invoice Item Table

Tags: sql

I read 
[Clustered Index Design Guidelines](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639(v=sql.105).aspx)
and tried to follow [The Clustered Index Debate Continues…](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) but really didn't understand it.

But this has to be a common example:
I have an Invoice table with InvoiceId as Primary Key-  Clusterand.

I have InvoiceItems table with InvoiceItemId as the Primary key and InvoiceId as the foriegn key

It seems to me that I would want to make InvoiceId in the items table the cluster index.  My thought process is :

- that 99% of the queries are going to be for the entire invoice and not by InvoiceItemId.  InvoiceItemId is more of an internal mechanism for keeping track of each item.
- While not unique it is close to unique
- It will be used in ranged queries

Is this the right design decision why or why not?

Comment: bench mark for your query workload

Comment: How so?  Is there a tool for that?  The current database has 3439 SPs about 30-50% of that is Invoice related.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was pretty well spelled out in [your first link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639(v=sql.105).aspx).

> Consider using a clustered index for queries that do the following
>
> - Return a range of values by using operators such as BETWEEN, >, >=, <, and <=.
> - [...]
> - Use JOIN clauses; typically these are foreign key columns.